# Modern equivalent to DPMI

Tags: x86

In the old days of DOS there was DPMI (DOS Protected Mode Interface). I allowed amongst other things the ability for your programs to break the 640K barrier.

In more modern times with CPUs having EMT64 (Extended Memory 64 Technology) i7s with 12 gig ram, is there an equivalent technology that allows me to use this extra memory from a 32bit app on a non 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [AWE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366531%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

With the Physical Address Extension feature (see [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) on Wikipedia, for example) of some x86 and x86-64 processors, you can theorically use up to 64 GiB of memory.

Comment: As you write, theoretically. In practice it has never worked like intended in the OSses which supported it. 32 Bit Windows versions newer than 2000 have disabled PAE because most drivers do not support it. In 32 bit Linux PAE does work, but it doesn't increase the address space.